# Where does Compton look for its conf file?

Tags: compton

One tutorial about installing Compton says that its in "~/" and called ".compton.conf". (In HOME, and note the prepended period on the file name)

Another tutorial says it's in "~/.config/" and called "compton.conf". This tutorial has the prepended period in the directory name, and in a directory under HOME.

Which is it?

Thanks!

Tutorial 1: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468&p=12644745#post12644745

Tutorial 2: http://duncanlock.net/blog/2013/06/07/how-to-switch-to-compton-for-beautiful-tear-free-compositing-in-xfce/

"apt list --installed | grep compton" returns "compton/xenial,now 0.1~beta2-1 amd64"

Comment: Maybe you should link to the tutorial so that we can see the context,

Comment: Also mention the source and version of Compton. `apt list --installed | grep compton` tells me I have `compton/xenial,now 0.1~beta2-1` and compton.conf is in ~/.config.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, why not try it yourself? Just do
`gedit ~/.config/compton.conf` (yes it's there)
But I believe you've long found your answer. This answer is for anyone who wants an answer here and now. Have a nice day!